# Parse Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a database I need to split into distinct values.

Example column data : Column name is Building / Room

```
Russel 103B,
Womans North 208,
NEWRH 1045A,
```

The only thing that remains the same is the last value is the room number, but it can be 3,4 or 5 characters (`substring("building / room",Length-4,4`)

Working with spaces doesn't work because of the second example where the building has two words.

I have tried using a `set IN ('Russel','Womans North','NEWRH')` but really need to address this dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think some string manipulation using the reversed string does what you want:

```
select right(br, charindex(' ', reverse(v.br) + ' ') - 1)
from (values ('Russel 103B,'), ('Womans North 208,'), ('NEWRH 1045A,')) v(br);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed907144ad9a1828f310b92ca3857a5b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Short and Clean

```
select  left([Building / Room],patindex('%[0-9]%',[Building / Room])-2)
from    mytable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48ef7/4/0)

P.S. If I would use `BR` instead of `[Building / Room]` it would look like this:

```
select  left(BR,patindex('%[0-9]%',BR)-2)
from    mytable
```